# Pass value of inputfield to controller without binding it to any object

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, inputfield

I a div popup where there is an input field

```
            <apex:inputfield id="CommentDate" value="{!AModel.dateTimeofComment}"/> 
            <apex:commandButton action="{!AModel.saveComment}" value="Save" id="saveButton"/>         
            <input type="submit" value="Cancel" class="btn" onclick="window.reload(); return false;" />
```

Here what I want is to pass the value of dateTimeofComment to the controller on savebutton click, without binding the value to any object. I tried using a getter setter global valiable, but that is not working either. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use apex:param for the solution. See the link do know more about it...https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_param.htm

Answer (score 0):

From your Visualforce, you appear to have a class (referenced via the property `AModel`) that has all the necessary plumbing. You just need to use the `dateTimeofComment` value in the `saveComment` method:

```
public DateTime dateTimeofComment {get; set;}

public PageReference saveComment() {
    // You can just use the dateTimeofComment value in here as it will be automatically
    // populated from the input field by Visualforce's bi-directional data binding
}
```